# problems with connecting a child component with the store in react-redux app

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

am working on react app for the first time and learn about redux. the problem I define a store in App.js and pass it to application using Provider bu when I try to access it to a child component I have an **undefined** in my console after map it with **mapStateToProps**. please can you check my code and tell me what am doing wrong?

I create a 2 reducers in folders reducers call index.js and testIt.js after that I import testIt.js in index.js which have a combineReducers to add feature reducers. after i export it for the App.js and Provide the store using the provider of react-redux.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter , Route} from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Store from "./reducers/index";
import { TestIt } from "./components/TestIt";

import './App.css';

//console.log(Store.getState());

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      
      <div className="App">
        <Provider store={Store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={TestIt} />
        </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
      </div>
      
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';
import notes from "./testIt";

const leadApp = combineReducers({
  notes
})

export default createStore(leadApp);
```

reducers/testIt.js

```
test .js

const initialState = [
    {text: "Write code!"}
  ];
  
  
  export default function notes(state=initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

finally my sub-component src/components/TestIt.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';


export class TestIt extends Component {
  
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.notes)
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Welcome to TestIt!</h2>
        <hr />
        <h3>Notes</h3>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            {this.props.notes.map(note => (
              <tr>
                <td>{note.text}</td>
                <td><button>edit</button></td>
                <td><button>delete</button></td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return notes : state.notes
}

// const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
//   return {
//   }
// }


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TestIt);
```

I have now this.props.notes give me **undefined** of the reducers **testIt.j** .I suspect something on the store I pass to to the **provider** does not reach the sub-component even if i do the connection with the method **connect()**. I expect to access to the testIt.js reducers in my sub component.

**Please really need help I try and read to much articles and documentations.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks.
i find a way to resolve my problem
removing **export** before **class** in TestIt.js resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return notes : state.notes
}
```

not getting the value in state.notes because you are assigning the state in notes.state

**Your code:-**

```
switch (action.type) {
  default:
    return state;
}
```

so you will get the value in state.notes.state

**If you want to change state property then you can change the code:-**

```
export default function notes(state=initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      default:
        return {data:state};
    }
  }
```

**sub-component src/components/TestIt.js**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return notes : state.notes.data
}
```

but this is not a good solution because this reducers not having any action type, so it will execute every time.

Comment: apply your changes but not **work** still **undefined**

Comment: plz find the updated comment you will find the value in const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {notes : state.notes.state };
}; from your code

Comment: **already fixed** my problem i do export at the level at the class and also on the end of file **TestIT.js**